# Solve multiple installation of LibreOffice

Tags: updates, libreoffice, versions

after a routine update of Ubuntu 22 I now have multiple versions of LibreOffice (7.3.7.2 and 7.5.1.2).

Is it possible to merge the two (as to keep the plugins I placed in 7.3 but not present in the newer version 7.5)? Or to upgrade 7.3 straight to 7.5 without duplication?

Is this due to a deb/snap communication flaw?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your details; Ubuntu Core 22 is a different product to the more widely used Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with 22 & 22.04/22.10 being able to use different package options.  22 is limited to *snap* only, where 22.04 & 22.10 can use other choices (*deb*, *flatpak*, *appimage* etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to merge the two. Your plugins are not interoperable. You cannot easily move a plugin from one to another.

"*Is this due to a deb/snap communication flaw?*"

Only in the sense that debs and snaps do not communicate with each other at all.

This looks like a variation on the classic case of wanting newer software on an older LTS release. Newer software is in newer releases of Ubuntu, and folks who want newer software might consider migrating to the 6-month releases of Ubuntu. For example, 23.04 (currently in pre-release testing) comes with LibreOffice 7.5.

Alternately, you can continue to use you existing LibreOffice 7.5, and simply hide (instead of uninstalling) the older 7.3. LibreOffice is part of the stock install of Ubuntu, so that older version might reinstall unexpectedly if you give apt the wrong instruction. Better to just hide that older version to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think is more a case ok clicking YES to the automatic update without knowing what goes under the hood. Can I selectively remove the newer version of LibreOffice 7.5 and keep only the older 7.3?

Comment: Merely clicking "yes" on Software Updater would generally keep your 7.3, NOT install 7.5. How to remove 7.5 and keep 7.3 is a very different question than keeping 7.5 or apt./snap communication. If you really want to remove 7.5 and keep 7.3, please open a new question, as removing 7.5 will depend upon how you actually installed it.

Comment: If clicking YES to the routine system updates, I don't get how 7.5 was installed in the first place then. Thanks for the tip on the additional post.